# NE555 pulse extender for PIN photodiode radiation detector is it fast enough? And more

Tags: 555, radiation, step-response

[image: PIN photodiode radiation detector]

I've designed a circuit using a PIN photodiode for a radiation detector aimed at identifying radium in an old watch. However, I'm uncertain about its effectiveness, particularly regarding the speed of the NE555 timer in detecting pulses from the radiation source. I'm also exploring alternatives to the NE555 timer, such as using common components like BC547 and BC557 transistors in conjunction with resistors and capacitors.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions you may have, as I'm relatively new to this field but have found it unexpectedly captivating. Electronics has become a hobby for me, and I welcome any guidance or recommendations to enhance the circuit.

Comment: I don’t see any problem using 555 for 1ms timing/stretching. It do the job the same as transistor timer. Just be sure you are getting the trigger pulses from comparator.

Comment: If you're not too picky about timing and just need to see whether a pulse happens or not, that *should* work (though use a modern CMOS 555 variant, not the antique NE555), though you need to be careful you don't add too much capacitance to the input node that you miss pulses.